# Matlab: work with 2NxN matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix 2NxN.

And I want get some parametrs by this matrix. For example it:

[image]
How, I can do it?

Comment: I don't think I understand how you get z-bar. From the picture it's just `z-bar(i,j)` = `z(i+1,j)` ? Is it the avg of the two matrix at position (i,j) ?

Comment: z_ij and z-bar_ij - this is a two linked elements from this matrix, where z-bar_ij under z_ij. Values in this cells does not necessarily the same.

Comment: I want to work with the matrix 12x6 just as 6x6

Comment: I also have no idea what the last one is...

Comment: last equation is the matrix generating by p_ij

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to break your **12x6** matrix, into two **6x6** matrix; let's say: `Z` and `Zb` (last one for z bar). Odd rows are `Z` and evens are `Zb`.

Considering `M` to be the combined matrices:

```
Z = M(1:2:end,:)
Zb = M(2:2:end,:)
```

read about the [colon(`:`) operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) and [`end`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html) to see what `1:2:end` means.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand here are the first three:

```
% Random Matrix
% Needs to be defined before the functions since the functions look for
% the m variable
m = rand(12,6);

% Function 1
p = @(i,j) sign(m(i,j)+m(i+1,j)) * max(abs(m(i,j)),abs(m(i+1,j)));
p(2,2)

% Function 2 - Avg of row
pavg = @(i) mean(m(i,:));
pavg(2)

% Function 3
c = @(i,j) abs(m(i,j)+m(i+1,j)) / (abs(m(i,j)) + abs(m(i+1,j)));
c(2,2)
```